# People Search Core results Web Part prompting credentials for each user in the result

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, people-search

People Search Core results Web Part is prompting user credentials for each result on the page. For instance if I get 3 results, the credentials prompt is appearing three times. I suspect that these prompts are only for the images of the user as other properties are getting displayed if I cancel the prompt. Is there a workaround for this issue ?

Thanks!

Comment: Issues occur when images are not published.

Comment: Those images are not a part of site assets. They are profile pictures from user profiles. Do they need publishing as well ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable cross domain photo setting.

Try below code:

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://sitecollectionurl
$wa.CrossDomainPhotosEnabled = $true
$wa.Update()
```

Reference- [Enable cross domain photo](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-enabling-cross-domain-profile-pictures)

Comment: This works for all subsites too , right ?

Comment: yes for subsites in this web application.